# How to rename a file in C using system() rather than rename()

Tags: c, printf, system, rename

I've been trying to rename a file in my C program. For the assignment we're supposed to use System() cp even though I've already done it using rename(). This is what I've tried so far, but it isn't working. I'm not sure if I've implemented the sprintf command correctly:

```
char oldName[] = "database.tmp"; 
char newName[] = "database.csv";
char rename[100];
sprintf(rename,"cp %s %s", oldName, newName);
system(rename);
```

I've also tried "cp -r %s %s" in the sprintf function and this didn't work either.

P.S. Thanks for your help!

Comment: How did it not work and what system are you using? This would not be the same on windows and linux for instance.

Comment: Are you sure you read the assignment correctly?  *Cp* is for CoPying files, not renaming them *mv* (MoVe) is for renaming.   Also, remember to account for spaces in the file names.

Comment: Read the documentation for your host system and compiler.   A call of `system(command)` typically uses a command-line interpreter or shell to execute the `command`, and the syntax varies with that interpreter/shell.    The interpreter/shell used can also depend on system settings and/or environment variables, and behaviour can depend on other settings or environment variables (like the path).    Under unix, `mv` is typically a program (although it may be a built-in with some shells) for moving/renaming files, not `cp`.

Comment: It's like your teacher *wants* you to write insecure, non-portable code...

Answer (score 0):

Use ren instead of cp in system() function to rename the file.

```
char oldName[] = "database.tmp"; 
char newName[] = "database.csv";
char rename[100];
sprintf(rename,"ren %s %s", oldName, newName);
system(rename);
```

Comment: My professor said specifically to use cp...I'm not sure how this would be done though.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
            char oldName[] = "database.tmp";
            char newName[] = "database.csv";
            char rename[100];
            sprintf(rename ,"mv %s %s" , oldName , newName);
            system(rename);
            return 0;
    }
```